# Doesnt \n remain in the buffer?

Tags: c, printf, buffer, ascii

Why does the program work fine when I use only integers? After I insert a number for variable 'a' and then press enter, doesn't `\n` remain in the buffer? If it indeed remains, then why can I initialize `b` also? If I had defined `b` as a char then the `b` output would `b 10`; in other words, the <s>null</s> newline character. If, for example, I wanted to enter a name many times for a number of the people using *(using what?)*, would I have any problem? Do I need a function that clears the buffer? So what's wrong and how can I solve this problem

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
   int a,b;
   
  printf("a ");
  scanf("%d",&a);
  printf("a=%d",a);
  
  printf("\nb ");
  scanf("%d",&b);
  printf("b=%d",b);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Most `scanf` formats will read and discard leading white space (e.g. space, tab, *and newline*).

So, in the shown code, the newline will be left after the first call to `scanf`. But the second call to `scanf` will read and discard it. However, the newline after that input will be left in the input buffer.

The only three `scanf` formats that do *not* read and discard leading white space are `%c`, `%[…]` (scan sets) and `%n`. If you want the same behavior for those formats, you need to add an explicit leading space in the format string yourself.

---

Because error handling and invalid input could be hard to handle with `scanf`, I always recommend using `fgets` to read a whole line instead. Then, you can use, e.g. `sscanf` to parse the line.

This way, if there's invalid input, it will not be left in the input buffer.

Answer (score 0):

For most of its conversions, including `%d`, `scanf` starts by reading and ignoring initial white-space characters, including the new-line character. Only for the conversions with `[`, `c`, or `n` does it not skip white-space characters.

To tell `scanf` to skip white-space characters before processing `%c`, insert a space in the format: `scanf(" %c", &b);`.

Comment: ok if the case was %c then how i can make the programm to ingore new -line characters ?because if i a was an interger and b char  i would have problems